# pandas evaluating strings as numeric

Tags: python, pandas, eval

assume df as;

```
data = {'duration':['1week 3day 2hour 4min 23', '2hour 4min 23sec', '2hour 4min', np.nan, '', '23sec']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'm trying to calculate the duration as sum of seconds. Replaced the values as:

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].str.replace('week', '*604800+') \
                                                                 .str.replace('day', '*604800+') \
                                                                 .str.replace('hour', '*3600+') \
                                                                 .str.replace('min', '*60+') \
                                                                 .str.replace('sec', '')  \
                                                                 .str.replace(' ', '')
```

But cant run eval functions like (pd.eval, apply.eval, eval etc). Some cells ends with '+' sign or other string/na problems.. Any help?

Ps: This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: "other string/na problems": Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'd write this as a function to work on an individual string (or even just a part of the string, such as `1week`) then use `apply` on your dataframe.  You probably don't want to use `eval` here

Comment: Empty strings causes exception, eval functions doesnt accept them. I'm not sure but i think na values causes exceptions too, error message (dtype error) was not clear enough to be sure.

Comment: The entry `2hour 4min` will give you a trailing `+` which you could check for, but I think you're taking the wrong approach altogether.

Comment: I'm open for any solution/approach

Comment: To justify "probably don't want to use `eval`": [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/5358968) but pandas eval might be alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex combined to a custom function to replace weeks by 7 days and add seconds on lonely numbers (you can add other units). Then convert [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
def change_units(m):
    d = {'week': (7, 'days'), '': (1, 's')}
    _, i, period = m.groups()
    factor, txt = d[period]
    return f'{factor*int(i)}{txt}'
    
df['delta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'].str.replace(r'((\d)\s*(week|)\b)',
                                                         replace, regex=True))
```

output:

```
                   duration            delta
0  1week 3day 2hour 4min 23 10 days 02:04:23
1          2hour 4min 23sec  0 days 02:04:23
2                2hour 4min  0 days 02:04:00
3                       NaN              NaT
4                                        NaT
5                     23sec  0 days 00:00:23
```

Then you can benefit from the TimeDelta object, for example to convert to [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'].str.replace(r'((\d)\s*(week|)\b)',
                                           change_units, regex=True)
               ).dt.total_seconds()
```

output:

```
0    871463.0
1      7463.0
2      7440.0
3         NaN
4         NaN
5        23.0
Name: duration, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @maxime have you checked the second part of the answer?

Comment: Thanks. it works on sample df but not on real one. exception as: `symbols w/o a number.  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ValueError: symbols w/o a number` BTW I think code skips rows begin with hour(row 3 become na)

Comment: this should be quite easy to fix, can you provide example of such rows?

Comment: regarding the row 3 it was a NaN in your example,  updated the answer to show the before/after conversion side by side, so there is no issue here

Comment: Sorry you are right, i forgot the blank string value. BTW exception message does not show the row that caused error

Comment: you can add `errors='coerce'` as parameter to `to_timedelta` to transform the invalid rows to NaT

Comment: I was just trying it right now. it worked, thanks for your help

Comment: let me know if you identify the invalid rows and need to handle them differently

Answer (score 1):

I had a different approach to the [excellent accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259546/5358968):

I wrote a function to convert the string into seconds:

```
def convert_all(s):
    if not isinstance(s, str):
        # E.g. for np.nan
        return s
    return sum(convert_part(part) for part in s.split())

def  convert_part(part):
    """Convert an individual segment into seconds.

    >>> convert_part('1day')
    86400.0
    """
    if part.isnumeric():
        return float(part)
    in_seconds = {'week': 7*24*60*60, 'day': 24*60*60, 'hour': 60*60, 'min': 60, 'sec': 1}
    for k,v in in_seconds.items():
        if part.endswith(k):
            return float(part.strip(k))*v
    else:
        # Handle error here - just printing for now
        print(part)
        return 0.0
```

then you can use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['duration_sec'] = df['duration'].apply(convert_all)
```

Output:

```
                   duration  duration_sec
0  1week 3day 2hour 4min 23      871463.0
1          2hour 4min 23sec        7463.0
2                2hour 4min        7440.0
3                       NaN           NaN
4                                     0.0
5                     23sec          23.0
```